# does SAML have a M2M flow?

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, m2m

can SAML somehow do a M2M flow like OAuth client credential? I need a service user to authenticate without credential prompts or human interactions

I found something called SAML Passive but I can't understand if it fits my scenario